# Authenticity of Sunan Abu Dawud 4464 on bestiality

Tags: hadith, authenticity

On sunnah.com, this specific hadith is graded as Sahih by Albani. However, within the hadith, Abu Dawud claims that the hadith is not strong. So is Albani saying that Abu Dawud is wrong and that this hadith actually is strong?

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said: If anyone has sexual intercourse with an animal, kill him and kill it along with him. I (Ikrimah) said: I asked him (Ibn Abbas): What offence can be attributed to the animal/ He replied: I think he (the Prophet) disapproved of its flesh being eaten when such a thing had been done to it.
>
> Abu Dawud said: This is not a strong tradition.
> ([Sunan abi Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:4464))

Comment: Maybe a better formulation is why did al-Albani claim it is hassan sahih when others said otherwise. As the related agreed fiqh rulings are actually have a difference to the hadith statement.

Comment: Albani has argued that this hadith is authentic (see [Irwa al-Ghalil 2348](https://shamela.ws/book/22592/2619)) and so have some other scholars. The authenticity of this hadith is disputed. Abu Dawud and others weaken it because of the conflict with the [later](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:4465) hadith however some have not accepted this line of reasoning because this hadith is marfoo' and stronger and corroborated, and because there are possible reconciliations between the two. Also see [What is the punishment of bestiality in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37356/).

Comment: @UmH By the way, the later hadith (4465) seems to be claiming that this is Ibn Abbas' personal oppinion unlike the previous hadith (4464) which is claiming that it's a statement/ruling directly from the prophet. So if Albani is right about it's authenticity, then wouldn't 4464 have more weight than 4465? Thus wouldn't the more correct opinion be that there is a hadd for this action even though there is a consensus amongst the Madhabs that the punishment is Tazir?